# Checkbox Label in a LWC with hyperlink

Tags: lightning-web-components, checkbox, label

I am building a LWC component that should be used on a website via Lightning Out. I need a checkbox with a hyperlink in the label similar to this one:
[image]
I tried to use the lightning-input with a hidden label and then add a label tag like in the code below.

```
       <lightning-layout-item size="12" medium-device-size="12" padding="around-small" >
            <div class=bdy>
                <lightning-input
                    type="checkbox"
                    variant="label-hidden"
                    label="l"
                    id=datenschutz>
                </lightning-input>
                <label for=datenschutz>
                Checkbox Label <a href="https://www.visitlondon.com/de">London</a>
                </label>
            </div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
```

Unfortunately the checkbox and the label are rendered in two separate lines.
[image]

How do I get them on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to align the label with the checkbox you could levarage [`slds-grid`](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/) class that create a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox), so just replacing your custom `bdy` class with `slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center` should be enough:

```html
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center">
    <lightning-input
        type="checkbox"
        variant="label-hidden"
        label=" ">
    </lightning-input>
    <label class="slds-checkbox__label">
        <span class="slds-form-element__label">Checkbox Label <a href="https://www.visitlondon.com/de">London</a></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I removed the `id` attribute since it [may be changed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-components-accessibility-attributes.html) by the framework.

By the way, you could also follow the [Checkbox blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox/) to build your own component or using a standard `<input type="checkbox">` instead of a `lightning-input`

Comment: thank you. It is working.
I tried the Checkbox blueprint of the SLDS but that removed my custom font of the whole component somehow.